# Git - why password-less push doesn't update the remote?

Tags: git, github, git-remote

I have to make notes while listening to lectures.

Can't store SSH keys and don't want to wait for username-password prompt (lecture doesn't stop); so when I have completed an exercise I do

```
git push https://username:password@github.com/username/repo.git master
```

the operation completes without error but when I do `git status` I get message saying there is a difference between local and remote repos. So I have to do the slow and blocking

```
git push origin master
```

and I type the username and password when prompted but then git says `everything is up to date` why this anomalous behavior?

---

Yesterday I forgot to do `git push origin master` at end of class and today in class when I did a `git clone ...` all the commits I made yesterday were lost and my repo was in state of day before yesterday. Is it possible to recover those?

Comment: `git status` shows the difference between your workspace and the current HEAD commit. Have you been checking your github if it changed every time you push `git push https://user:pass...` ?

Comment: Why not just set your username and password in git? Then you won't be prompted every time you push.

Comment: @smarber the workstation we get is donated material, launching a browser means wasting 2-3 minutes. Given I lost my changes, perhaps github's copy isn't updating

Comment: @AdamS how do I do that, `git push`'s help page doesn't cover how to set credentials in git. Can you point me to correct resources?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store

Comment: @AdamS `git config user.name ...` and `git config user.password ...` modifies the `.git/config` file but I still need to enter all stuff when doing `git push origin master`

Comment: @smarber thanks. I got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the conditions set by OP, I think this is a possible solution

Create a file, in the home directory, named `.git-credentails` which should contain the following line

```
https://username:password@github.com
```

replace `username` and `password` with appropriate strings and next time OP does a `git push origin master` s/he won't be prompted for manually entering credentials (iff protocol, hostname, and username pattern match the url of your repository's origin).

As usual, the best place to get precise information is -- https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store